# How do we conclude that $f(x)=0, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, periodic-functions

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a periodic function such that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=0}$.

I want to show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

$$$$

Let $T$ be the period of $f$, then $f(x)=f(x+T)$.

Therefore, we have that $$0=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x+T)=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x+2T)=\dots =\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x+nT), \ \forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

So, $$|f(x)|=|f(x+T)|=|f(x+2T)|=\dots =|f(x+nT)|\leq \epsilon$$

$$$$

But how exactly do we conclude that $f(x)=0, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: You already proven it, you did an argument that works form an arbitrary x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $x_n:=x+nT$ tends to $+\infty$ ($T$ is the period of $f$) and $f(x_n)=f(x)$ for all $n$, since $f$ is $T-$periodic. Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=0$, we get that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f(x_n)=0$ and by the uniqueness of the limit, we get $f(x)=0$, as desired.

Comment: We have that $f(x_n)=f(x), \forall n$ and that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=0$. How do we get the limit as for $n$, $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f(x_n)=0$ ? Also how do we conclude by the uniqueness of the limit that $f(x)=0$ ?

Comment: For the first part, the following equivalence (sequential characterization) holds : $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=\ell \in \mathbb{R}\iff$ for every sequence $(x_n)$ that tends to $+\infty$ we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}f(x_n)=\ell$  - so all you have to do is to apply the $\rightarrow$ part for the sequence $x_n=x+nT$.  For the second part, every convergent sequence of reals has a unique limit (classic result). Since $(f(x_n))$ converges both to $f(x)$ (as constant) and $0$, as shown, we have the desired result.

Comment: I got it!! Thank you so much!! :-)

Comment: you are welcome ;-)

Answer (score 3):

$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=0$ for all sequences with $\lim x_n=\infty$.  If there exist some $x\in\mathbb R$ for which $f(x)\neq0$, then let $x_n=x+nT$ and get a contradiction.

Comment: I see... Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hint :From your argument - if there is some point $a$ such that $f(a) \neq 0$ then there is a sequence of such points (In specific, a sequence that us not bounded)

Comment: What do you mean by "then there is a sequence of such points" ?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) =0$ is equivalent to the condition  that for all $\epsilon >0$ that there exists $N$ large enough such that we have $\left|f(x)\right| < \epsilon$ when $x>N$. There must also exist an integer $m$ such that $mT > N$. So then $\left|f(x)\right| = \left|f(x + mT)\right| < \epsilon$ and this was regardless of our choice of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Ah ok... Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely have the right idea by showing that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x+nT)$ for $n \in \Bbb{Z}$. However, we need to use that with the definition of limits to prove this theorem. Now, I am going to say that we are proving $f(x_0)=0$ for some arbitrary $x_0 \in \Bbb{R}$. That way, when I use $x$ below, I'm talking about a general input into $f$ while $x_0$ is the value we are trying to prove that $f(x_0)=0$ for the theorem.

Let's say we pick an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, as you did. Then, by the definition of limits as $x \to +\infty$, there exists an $M$ such that $|f(x)-0|=|f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x > M$. Now, let us choose $x > M$ such that $x=x_0+nT$ for some $n \in \Bbb{Z}$. If we choose $x=M+1=x_0+M-x_0+1=x_0+\frac{M-x_0+1}{T}T$, then we have $x > M$ and $x=x_0+nT$ for some $n \in \Bbb{R}$, but we can't be sure that $n$ is an integer. To mak $n$ an integer, we take the ceiling function of it, so we have $x=x_0+\lceil\frac{M-x_0+1}{T}\rceil T$. Now, $x > M$ still holds true, but we are sure that $n \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Now, since $x=x_0+nT$ for $n \in \Bbb{Z}$, we know that $f(x)=f(x_0)$. Thus, $|f(x_0)|<\epsilon$. We can do this for any $\epsilon > 0$, meaning we can bring $f(x_0)$ arbitrarily close to $0$. Now, we will prove $f(x_0)=0$ by contradiction.

Let's say $f(x_0) \neq 0$. Then, choose $\epsilon=\frac{|f(x_0)|}{2}$. Since $\epsilon > 0$, $|f(x_0)|<\frac{|f(x_0)|}{2}$. By dividing both sides by $|f(x)|$, we get $1<\frac 1 2$, which is a contradiction. Thus, our original assumption that $f(x_0) \neq 0$ is false and $f(x_0)=0$ for all $x_0 \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot!! :-)

Comment: I'm glad that we could all help!